# Power BI dataflow not getting all IDs for a "Person and Group" SharePoint column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, google-cloud-dataflow, powerbi-datasource

I have a dataflow that gets data from a "Person and Group" SharePoint column (pulls in the ID) but it's not bringing in the ID for every item that has a name in the column. In some cases where there is a name, it acts like the name isn't there and just puts "null" in the results table.
Why does it do that for some, and for others, it pulls in the ID?

[image: Power Query Editor column]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to add the column name to a SelectColumns function in one of the applied steps of a query in the dataflow.